# How do I prevent running out of memory when inserting a million rows in mysql with php

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have built a script in Laravel that reads a JSON file line by line and imports the contents into my database.

However, when running the script, I get an out of memory error after inserting about 80K records.

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 421527552) (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /home/vagrant/Code/sandbox/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php on line 1758

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory
PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 421527552) (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /home/vagrant/Code/sandbox/vendor/symfony/debug/Exception/FatalErrorException.php on line 1
```

I have built a sort of makeshift queue to only commit the collected items every 100, but this made no difference.

This is what the part of my code that does the inserts looks like:

```
public function callback($json) {

    if($json) {

        $this->queue[] = [

            'type' => serialize($json['type']),
            'properties' => serialize($json['properties']),
            'geometry' => serialize($json['geometry'])
        ];

        if ( count($this->queue) == $this->queueLength ) {

            DB::table('features')->insert( $this->queue );

            $this->queue = [];
        }
    }
}
```

It's the actual inserts (`DB::table('features')->insert( $this->queue );`) that are causing the error, if I leave those out I can perfectly iterate over all lines and echo them out without any performance issues.

I guess I could allocate more memory, but doubt this would be a solution because I'm trying to insert 3 million records and it's currently already failing after 80K with 512Mb memory allocated. Furthermore, I actually want to run this script on a low budget server.

The time it takes for this script to run is not of any concern, so if I could somehow slow the insertion of records down that would be a solution I could settle for.

Comment: bound to be laravel overhead, so i would stop using that for a start

Comment: The last time I had to do this, I wrote a cron script that ran every N hours and took N records, updating processed records with a flag. Every once in a while the script would fail, but it would just restart by selecting unprocessed records. Not the best solution (measing for possible overlapping, for one, so hoping someone here will shed a light on it. Edit: Dagon has a point too, it will increase perfomance significantly if you will custom build it.

Comment: You could pass in a set limit of N rows to your callback() method of whatever amount you *can* process at once. At the end of your method, redirect back to your page with an increase of N rows + N to process the next batch in your queue until it is empty.    ?

Comment: split the original json file into smaller files (let's say ~10K rows each) and run the script for each small file. Don't put it in the loop, literally, get the first file in dir, run script, delete the file, exit. than repeat until you run out of files. you may need a small bash script to automate this.

Comment: I just tried the same script in Lumen, which is supposed to be a lightweight version of Laravel for more API type stuff and the import worked flawlessly! I'm confused however, because if I'm not mistaken Laravel and Lumen actually use the same database components, so where would this huge difference in overhead be coming from? The entire application is only getting instantiated and booted once, and that only takes up a few megabytes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On scaffolding my application I installed the [itsgoingd/clockwork](https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork) package. It's a habit I've gotten into because it's such a useful tool. (I recommend any Laravel devs reading this to check it out!)

Of course this package logs queries for debugging purposes and thus, was the culprit eating up all of my memory.

Disabling the package by deleting the reference to its service provider in my configuration solved the issue.

Cheers to @dbushy727 for giving me a push in the right direction to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

If you use MySQL 5.7+, it has feature for importing data from JSON file using `LOAD DATA INFILE`.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'afile.json' INTO TABLE atable (field1, field2, ....);
```

If you use lower MySQL version then you need to convert JSON into CSV format first. For example using https://github.com/danmandle/JSON2CSV

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'afile.csv' INTO TABLE atable (field1, field2, ....);
```

See `LOAD DATA INFILE`'s [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Comment: Hey that's something I didn't know about! Unfortunately I need to considerably change the way this data is structured before I enter it into my database.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE is best if you have very big data to be inserted at once. It will be much faster than INSERT

Comment: I might try this sometime out of curiosity. My current solution however is plenty fast! It takes about 15 minutes to import 3 million rows which I'm happy with.

Comment: In this solution- bear in mind that file should be on same server as mysql server itself. Normally, it won't work if you have separate mysql server.

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure your query logging is off. If your query logging is on, even though you are clearing out $this->queue, the query log is growing until it grows to an unmanageable size and you hit your memory limit.

To check if query logging is on or off, use the DB facade like this:

```
DB::logging()
```

If this returns true, then your logging is on, and that's your problem.
If this returns false, then it's some other configuration that is holding onto your queries.

Comment: Query logging is off. However, your comment gave me the hint I needed to find the issue as described in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

About problem, I think you should use message queue ( Gearman, Rabbit ... ) to fix this problem.

Fetch all record and push to queue. Queue will process one by one